# Find first negative occurrence or replace with flag if all values positive in columns of an array

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I have an array with 13 rows and 1189 columns. Each column has a range values, most of which have negative numbers, but ~100 don't have any negative values. I can find the first occurrence of the negative values with:

```
[I,J] = find(A<0)
[~,m] = unique(J,'first')
T = I(m)'
```

but I miss the columns that have only positive numbers. In the end I need an array that has the same number of columns as the input array with the indexes of the first occurrence of the negative value or a flag for columns with only positive values (a zero is fine). Here is an example of the array:

```
A = [0.3449    0.3299   -0.0431   -0.0391   -0.0391   -0.0441   -0.0511   -0.0611   -0.0701   -0.0711   -0.0591
0.3187    0.2947   -0.0353   -0.0283   -0.0243   -0.0243   -0.0273   -0.0313   -0.0363   -0.0363   -0.0313
0.2784    0.2614   -0.2046   -0.1926   -0.1786   -0.1616   -0.1466   -0.1416   -0.1456   -0.1486   -0.1436
0.1732    0.1682   -0.2358   -0.2208   -0.2018   -0.1798   -0.1608   -0.1488   -0.1458   -0.1468   -0.1468
0.1530    0.1380   -0.2130   -0.1860   -0.1590   -0.1340   -0.1120   -0.0970   -0.0870   -0.0840   -0.0870
0.1287    0.1067   -0.1143   -0.0853   -0.0663   -0.0563   -0.0493   -0.0403   -0.0273   -0.0163   -0.0133
0.0955    0.0705   -0.0605   -0.0365   -0.0235   -0.0225   -0.0225   -0.0165   -0.0015    0.0145    0.0225
0.2334    0.2084    0.1394    0.1554    0.1614    0.1584    0.1554    0.1614    0.1764    0.1944    0.2054
0.1819    0.1589    0.1099    0.1159    0.1169    0.1129    0.1089    0.1129    0.1239    0.1379    0.1479
0.1334    0.1114    0.0734    0.0704    0.0624    0.0504    0.0414    0.0434    0.0564    0.0744    0.0894
0.1209    0.1059    0.0629    0.0509    0.0369    0.0219    0.0109    0.0109    0.0219    0.0379    0.0529
0.1264    0.1124    0.0604    0.0414    0.0214    0.0014   -0.0116   -0.0116    0.0014    0.0204    0.0364
0.0989    0.0879    0.0449    0.0269    0.0079   -0.0111   -0.0231   -0.0241   -0.0141    0.0019    0.0169];
```

For this input array `A` the output array `T` should be:

```
T = [0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[My fav](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html):

```
[I,J] = find(A<0);
T = accumarray(J,I,[size(A,2) 1],@min,0).'
```

It says for each grouping of same column indexes find the first row index.  By specifying the output size it will automatically fill in missing rows elements with zeros.  Zero is the default, but I've specified for completeness

But with your current solution, init `T`  with zeros, followed by `T(J(m)) = I(m)` would do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Fo this kind of job I like to use [`max`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html) (two-output version):

```
[V, T] = max(A<0, [], 1);
T(~V) = 0; %// this "0" is the flag value. Change if needed
```